# Firebase and Android and cloud functions and other platforms

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I am planning to use firebase as a backend service for my android app. I discovered that I would need cloud functions for binding my app with firebase. I went through the docs and tutorials. Understood much but not everything. My doubts are:

1. Do I need to write a different set of cloud functions for different platforms(Like if I make web-app later or ios app.) If yes, what is
   the use of firebase other than server handling?
2. Do I need to write cloud functions for every feature of firebase that I use?
3. Automating push notification with firebase(Android App)?
4. How exactly does my app communicate with cloud functions and then firebase?

Answer (score 1):

> Cloud Functions for Firebase lets you automatically run backend code in response to events triggered by Firebase features and HTTPS requests.
>
> The functions you write can respond to events generated by these other Firebase and Google Cloud features.

You don't have to use cloud functions, you can use firebase features without cloud functions. You use cloud functions to respond to events, example if you add new data to the database, then you can use `onCreate()` that gets triggered when new data is created and you can handle that data.

You can also send welcome emails, using cloud functions when a new user is authenticated.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events#set_the_event_handler

> 1. Do I need to write a different set of cloud functions for different platforms(Like if I make web-app later or ios app.) If yes, what is the use of firebase other than server handling?

*No you don't need to do that*

> 2. Do I need to write cloud functions for every feature of firebase that I use?

*Every feature has different triggers, so when you want to respond to auth event you have to use it's [triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/#key_capabilities)*

> 3. Automating push notification with firebase(Android App)?

*Yes, you can send push notification in response to events that happen when you use firebase features, you need to also use FCM for that.*

> 4. How exactly does my app communicate with cloud functions and then firebase?

*1. The developer writes code for a new function, selecting an event provider (such as Realtime Database), and defining the conditions under which the function should execute.*

*2. The developer deploys the function, and Firebase connects it to the selected event provider.*

*3. When the event provider generates an event that matches the function's conditions, the code is invoked.*